# Spring Data MongoDB performing validation *after* saving to repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, lombok, spring-mongodb

I have simple `@Document` which on saving to MongoDB using *spring-data-mongodb* don't have any of the validation annotations applied.

Document:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.Instant;

@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "calls")
public class Call {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank("Owner ID is required")
    @Indexed
    private String ownerId;

    @NotNull
    private Instant createdAt;

}
```

Validator config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class MongoValidator {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

When I attempt to save to my `MongoRepository<Call, UUID>` I get the expected Exception thrown:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: null
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener.onBeforeSave(ValidatingMongoEventListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractMongoEventListener.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractMongoEventListener.java:31)
```

But only **after** the document is saved to the repository, not before.

Any ideas how to execute the validator before save?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the RestAdapter of Spring as follows:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class RestValidationConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
@Primary
/**
 * Create a validator to use in bean validation - primary to be able to autowire without qualifier
 */
Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}


@Override
public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
    Validator validator = validator();
    //bean validation always before save and create
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Spring Data REST. It also appears `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after stepping through the code in `MongoTemplate`.

I’d overridden the `@Bean` for `ApplicationEventMulticaster`:

```
@Bean
ApplicationEventMulticaster applicationEventMulticaster() {
    SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster eventMulticaster = new SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster();
    eventMulticaster.setErrorHandler(TaskUtils.LOG_AND_SUPPRESS_ERROR_HANDLER); // don't want to prevent further processing of event
    return eventMulticaster;
}
```

As a consequence an exception thrown in the `BeforeSaveEvent` listener called in `MongoTemplate` wasn’t halting the method `MongoTemplate.doSave`.